# SQL Report - Group by Query for getting data from 12 months ago (this month included)

Tags: sql, report

So, I found this nice little query:

```
Select    count(*) 
FROM      Table_X 
WHERE     year(DATE) = '2012' 
GROUP BY  month(DATE)
```

Which does almost exactly what I need.. Except I need to query the data of current month, up until 1 year ago. So for October, sept, aug, jul, jun, may, apr, mar, feb, jan 2012 and dec, nov 2011..

So I could just wait till the end of december to make the report :) . But there must be some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using DATEADD to calculate the date 12 months ago:

```
Select    count(*) 
FROM      Table_X 
WHERE     DATE > = DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE())
GROUP BY  month(DATE)
```

If the problem is more complicated than this, post it and I'll add to my answer.

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately, this returns 0 rows.. whereas my first query did return the required results

Comment: Small mistake, sorry. Reposting now! Please try again and let me know.

Comment: BTW, this code assumes 12 months back from today and no future data. If this assumption isn't correct....

Comment: great, that's what I was looking for :) I'll tweak it a little to get the right dates. Thanks for your reply